# C# WPF Constantly Update label from thread

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been trying to do one last thing for an app I've been developing to help me learn c# and I don't get why its not working the number wont update after one try its very annoying and help help would be appreciated thank you :)

```
int num = 1;
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => Connectorbutton.Content = num += 1));
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

the button is writing too only goes up one number even while its looped. I imagine its not updating the text but is in the background because I've tried to update it on the mainthread and it still wont update like I need it too. LMK if you have any ideas thank you for your time!

Comment: Please show all the code needed to understand the problem. Fo example, you write something about a loop, but you don't show this to us. Also, you should write what you try to achieve.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do like this. Your caller block your thread.

[image]

Result

[image]

Comment: thank you i completely forgot about ++num but also its still not updating the label over 2 maybe its the loop? ive tried a while (true) and a for (;;) loop so it continues on forever but its still stuck

Comment: This should at least be `private async void btnClick ...` and `await Task.Run(...)`

Comment: Besides that, inside the Task Action you could also write Thread.Sleep without blocking the UI thread, because the Task runs in a background thread.